# Why does the <count> escape sequence insert the current line number in my user command?

Tags: vimscript, count, user-commands

I've added the following to my *.vimrc* in order to test how `<count>` works in a user defined command because I was noticing odd behaviour:

```
:command! -count=1 CountTest :exe "echo " . <count> . "'" 
noremap <space> :CountTest<cr>
```

Now, when I type `:3CountTest` I get what I would expect, i.e., the number 3 is echoed into the prompt. However, when I try using my custom mapping to `<space>` (i.e. typing `3<space>`) I get 3 + *the current line number*.

I'm sure it's just a problem with the way I've assigned my custom mapping. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `:h map-examples`, it is mentioned that

> When you type a count before triggering a mapping, it's like the count
>   was typed before the {lhs}.

For your mapping, this means that the count is added before `:`. This means the actual command that is getting executed is, for count of 2:

```
:.,.+1CountTest
```

and for count of 5:

```
.,.+4CountTest
```

And the result of what you see is just how range given to a command which should take a count is handled. To handle the count correctly in the mapping, you can use

```
:nnoremap <space> :<C-u>exec v:count1 "CountTest"<CR>
```

Comment: Ahhhh thank you. I knew it was something like this but I couldn't get the syntax right. Cheers mate.